# Using gulp eslint how do I only report errors and warnings?

Tags: eslint

Essentially I just want to remove all the annoying successful messages I see in my report.
I'm not aware of any extension method on eslint that allows me to do this. I've had a go with .format and .results and .result hoping that each could return or filter out the results i don't want by reference.

Having no luck. Any help?